# RedirectMatch query string issue

Tags: apache, url-rewriting, query-string, match

I am moving content on a previous website where 2 copies of the site were made to translate it so that i only have one remaining.

To provide fallback access, i wrote this rewritematch rule :

```
RedirectMatch  301 /(en|fr)/(.+)\.php\??(.+)?       /$2.php?locale=$1&$3
```

But it doesn't seem to be working.

If i do the following instead, everything works fine but i lose the query string passed in the original link which i really want.

```
RedirectMatch  301 /(en|fr)/(.+)\.php               /$2.php?locale=$1&$3
```

Is there something i am doing wrong? Or are query strings not supported? (I checked but there seems to be no limitations on the apache docs).

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
RedirectMatch  301 /(en|fr)/(.+)(\.php\?)?(.+)?
```

Comment: tried this again. for this link : `http://localhost/en/view.php?id=103&abc` i get redirected to `http://localhost/view.php.php?locale=en/en/view.php` which is weird